# Creating horizontal cylinder with bottom node shape in TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I have found the following [reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182976/creating-cylinder-with-bottom-node-shape-in-tikz-pgf) which creates a vertical cylinder with a bottom. However I need a horizontal cylinder with a bottom, but can't seem to find an easy (and working) example. I tried using the rotated coordinate system from tikz-3dplot, but to no avail.
This is my testing code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in    your LaTeX installation
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}

\title{TikZ: cylinder with bottom - example}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=0.7,minimum height=4cm,minimum     width=3cm,shape border rotate=0,cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body     fill=red!30,cylinder end fill=red!10] (A) {A};

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{0}

\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords]
    let \p1 = ($ (A.after bottom) - (A.before bottom) $),
        \n1 = {0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)-\pgflinewidth},
        \p2 = ($ (A.bottom) - (A.after bottom)!.5!(A.before bottom) $),
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)-\pgflinewidth}
  in
    ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth] A.before bottom) arc [start angle=0, end angle=180,
    x radius=\n1, y radius=\n2];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

You just need to change how the `arc` is drawn. Your code has `start angle=0,end angle=180`, so it is the upper half of an ellipse, while you need the right half.

The starting point is the bottom of the cylinder, so you need `start angle=270`, and to get the correct part of the ellipse, use `delta angle=180` instead of `end angle=90`. You also need to swap the `x` and `y` radius, so the `arc` command becomes

```
arc [start angle=270, delta angle=180,
    x radius=\n2, y radius=\n1];
```

The `tikz-3dplot` stuff isn't needed. Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=0.7,minimum height=4cm,minimum     width=3cm,shape border rotate=0,cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body     fill=red!30,cylinder end fill=red!10] (A) {A};

\draw[dashed]
    let \p1 = ($ (A.after bottom) - (A.before bottom) $),
        \n1 = {0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)-\pgflinewidth},
        \p2 = ($ (A.bottom) - (A.after bottom)!.5!(A.before bottom) $),
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)-\pgflinewidth}
  in
    ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth] A.before bottom) arc [start angle=270, delta angle=180,
    x radius=\n2, y radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```